# Kivy RecycleView is not show full screen

Tags: kivy-language

I have to design to use RecycleView to show the button on screen. I created a search layout using GridLayout on top and RecycleView, but it does not show on full screen. How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeQRS.png)

**Kv File**

```
<ProductListViewMain>:
    SearchProduct:
        RV:

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Button'
    orientation: "vertical"
    RecycleGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        row_force_default: True
        row_default_height: 150
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

<SearchProduct>:
    cols: 1
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 300
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.898039, 0.898039, 0.909804, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        
    RelativeLayout:

        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Search'
            font_size: 45
            font_family: 'Roboto'
            background_color: 0.952941, 0.952941, 0.952941, 1
            foreground_color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 70
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 850
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
```